# How can I automount my drive immediately on connection rather than on first access?

Tags: systemd, automounting

I have an external drive set up in my `/etc/fstab` with `noatime,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=500ms,x-systemd.automount,users`.

I also have several dependencies set up which only start when this drive is mounted. Here is a snippet of their `.service` files:

```
[Unit]
Requires=home-pi-ssd.mount
After=network.target home-pi-ssd.mount
BindsTo=home-pi-ssd.mount

[Service]
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target home-pi-ssd.mount
```

The problem is, the drive does not mount upon connection, but only when the drive is first accessed. The `home-pi-ssd.mount`, and its dependent services, do not become `Active` until I, say, `ls ~/ssd`, after which they all start up as expected.

However, I really need these services to become active on **connection**, rather than having to manually trigger the automount trap. How can I make the mount happen immediately on connection rather than setting up a trap?

Comment: If you want to run actions when a device is plugged in, you should be looking at `udev` rules. E.g., https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461700/how-to-mount-usb-drive-in-udev-rule

Comment: Yes @larsks, it appears that using `udev` will solve this situation. Thank you!