# Why is NTFS has a dirty mark and why can't NTFS3 mount dirty NTFS partitions?

Tags: linux, kernel, mount, ntfs, udisks

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NTFS#Unable_to_mount_with_ntfs3_with_partition_marked_dirty

When a NTFS partition is marked dirty, NTFS3 cannot mount this on linux

But NTFS-3G (and also Windows) can

It seems that hot-unplugging an NTFS drive (unplugging it without "ejecting" it, then putting it in again) can cause the NTFS partition to be marked as dirty, like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230181/why-does-linux-mark-fat-as-dirty-simply-due-to-mounting-it). Theoretically, this should not cause any problems, as nowadays many devices support hot (un)plug.

Comment: hibernation is also an issue... and if you ignore it, you can suffer serious filesystem corruption. the device may support whatever, the question is what does the filesystem support... in general it's mandatory to umount/eject before you unplug. and disable hibernation/fastboot/whatever you call it, if you multi-boot

Answer (score 5):

> Why is NTFS has a dirty mark and why can't NTFS3 mount dirty NTFS partitions?

If the partition is marked dirty it means its metadata is inconsistent and using it in read write mode, e.g. for creating, modifying or deleting file system objects may result in a data loss. Normally chkdsk from Windows must be used to fix it. The `ntfsfix` utility does not actually fix inconsistencies, it often simply removes the dirty flag.

---

From https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/ntfs3.html and `man mount` if your distro is new enough:

```
force

Forces the driver to mount partitions even if volume is marked dirty. Not recommended for use.
```

```bash
sudo mount -o force,ro /dev/device /mnt/NTFS
```

Should work for you. Highly not recommended. At least you could use `ro` as an additional option to avoid damaging the partition.

Comment: Thanks! What should I do if I use udisks2 to mount?

Comment: Run `chkdsk` in Windows or mount `ro`.